# React Typescript Redux, Socket IO weird behaviour of socket.on("data"

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, socket.io, react-typescript

I have placed socket IO into my reducer. Based on this I am updating my state across component with the new data. In my reducer I have connect and disconnect triggered by actions (this happens after user logs in or logs out). I don't need the socket to connect and it even won't work as on my server I have authorisation that checks auth with DB.

If I place the connection at the top of the reducer the socket.on("connect, socket.on("diconnect and socket.on("data" works, but if I place the io connection inside the reducer only only socket.on("connect and socket.on("disconnect works and even if server emits any data they won't be received by client.

Code sample:

```
import { WS } from '../types';
import { wsConnect, wsDisconnect } from '../actions/ws';
import { wsGotDataByUnitSerial } from '../actions/units';
import { store } from '../store';
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';
import { WS_DOMAIN, WS_PORT } from '../config';

// socket variable
let socket: any;

// socket ID
let SOCKET_ID: string;





if(socket) {
  // SOCKET WS CONNECTED
  socket.on("connect", () => {
    console.log('CONNECTED')
    store.dispatch(wsConnect());
    SOCKET_ID = socket.id;
    console.log('DEBUG: [REDUCER] connected to socket ID:', SOCKET_ID);
  });

  // SOCKET WS DISCONNECTED
  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log('DISCONNECTED')
    store.dispatch(wsDisconnect());
    console.log('DEBUG: [REDUCER] disconnected from socket ID:', SOCKET_ID); // undefined
  });


  // SOCKET ON RECEIVING DATA
  socket.on("data", (message: string) => { 
    console.log('x', message)
    const data = JSON.parse(message);
    console.log('DEBUG: [REDUCER] received following data:', data.data);
    // OK - process the data
    if(data.status === 'ok') {
      const unitData = data.data;
      store.dispatch(wsGotDataByUnitSerial(unitData));
    }
    // ERROR - show message
    if(data.status === 'error') {
      console.error('[WS ERROR]', data.msg);
    }
  })
}



interface WsState {
  wsConnected: boolean
}


const DEFAULT_WS: WsState = {
  wsConnected: false
}


const ws = (state = DEFAULT_WS, action: any) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case WS.CONNECT:
      console.log('DEBUG: [REDUCER] WS.CONNECT');
      // connect to socket IO
      socket = io(`ws://${WS_DOMAIN}:${WS_PORT}`, { transports: ["websocket"] });
      console.log(socket)
      return { 
        ...state,
        wsConnected: true
      }
    case WS.DISCONNECT:
      console.log('DEBUG: [REDUCER] WS.DISCONNECT');
      // disconnect from socket IO
      socket.disconnect();
      return { 
        ...state,
        wsConnected: false
      }
```

The code looks all right. I don't understand why is it that if I place `` io(`ws://${WS_DOMAIN}:${WS_PORT}`, { transports: ["websocket"] }); `` just under `let socket: any` this will work, but naturally will cause problems as unauthenticated user won't authenticate in the socket server and the connection won't be created. Can anyone please help, offer some advice or present possible solution. Thank you for your kind help.